# I need to search for a string inside an document and print all the lines that has the word "Desktop"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I`m making a program that reads a document and after that it searches for specifics words and return the lines that has this words

I tried this sample but all it returns is an `"Process finished with exit code 0"`.

```
def main():


    f = open("xhtml.log", "r")

    line = f.readline()
    x= "Desktop"
    while line:

        #print(line)
        line = f.readline()
        print(line)
        if line == x:
            print(line)

    f.close()
```

in this log I have a lot of lines with desktop written on and I need it to be printedm, how do I do that?

Comment: `if 'Desktop' in line`.... You are checking to see if the entire line equals `Desktop`, not if `Desktop` is `in` that line. Also you should do `with open('xtml.log') as f:` and `for line in f:` don't use a while loop for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line == x` would only be `True` if the line is equal to that value. You need to use:

```
if x in line:
    print(line)
```

So that it searches for a matching string in each line, regardless of length of the line or the position of the string. Notice that this is case sensitive, and would only match `Desktop` and not `desktop`. If you want to find both, compare them with:

```
if x.lower() in line.lower():
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement `if line == x` only results in True if the line is exactly the same string as in x.

So if the line is "I have a big Desktop" and x is "Desktop" it would result in this comparison:

```
if "I have a big Desktop" == "Desktop":
    print("This will never print")
```

What you are looking for is:

```
if "Desktop" in "I have a big Desktop":
    print("This will print")
```

replaced with variables:

```
if x in line:
    print(line)
```